# Angular 4 Dropdown Example Usage

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu

I wanted to use a drop-down text for one of my form elements and I came across this: [ng4-material-dropdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng4-material-dropdown)

How could I use it? To me it is not clear from the example given in the description on how to use it:

It says:

```
<ng4-dropdown>
    <ng4-dropdown-button>
        Open Menu
    </ng4-dropdown-button>
    <ng4-dropdown-menu>
        <ng4-menu-item *ngFor="let page of pages">
            {{ page }}
        </ng4-menu-item>

        <div class='ng4-menu-divider'></div>

        <ng4-menu-item>
            With Divider
        </ng4-menu-item>
    </ng4-dropdown-menu>
</ng4-dropdown>
```

So from what I guess I only need the following:

```
<ng4-dropdown>
  <ng4-dropdown-menu>
    <ng4-menu-item *ngFor="let page of pages">
      {{ page }}
    </ng4-menu-item>
  </ng4-dropdown-menu>
</ng4-dropdown>
```

But what is this page? Where is it coming from? Do I replace my model with this? Suggestions?

EDIT: I created an array in my xxx.component.ts caled pages and I have 3 elements in in that I want to show as a drop down. When I tried it as-is, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setGlobalVar' of null
    at _createNgProbe (ng4-dropdown.bundle.js:6944)
    at eval (module.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
    at _callFactory (core.es5.js:9561)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.es5.js:9490)
    at initNgModule (core.es5.js:9441)
    at new NgModuleRef_ (core.es5.js:10555)
    at createNgModuleRef (core.es5.js:10539)
    at Object.debugCreateNgModuleRef [as createNgModuleRef] (core.es5.js:12833)
    at NgModuleFactory_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.NgModuleFactory_.create (core.es5.js:13828)
    at core.es5.js:4497
```

Any ideas as to what this error is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app.component.html

```
<ng4-dropdown>
          <ng4-dropdown-menu>
            <ng4-menu-item *ngFor="let page of pages">
              {{ page }}
            </ng4-menu-item>
          </ng4-dropdown-menu>
        </ng4-dropdown>
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent{
pages =['abc','bca','pqr'];
}
```

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at my edited post? I get some strange error when I tried it!

Answer (score -1):

The page which is shown on the npmjs plugin page is your template page. You will be placing that code in the template of your component in which you want to use that plugin.
You will first install the plugin using this command

```
npm install ng4-material-dropdown --save
```

After install you need to add it to your `NgModule` so your app can recognize this new plugin.

Import the plugin add it to the imports property array of your `NgModule` (it will be app.module.ts file)

```
import { Ng4DropdownModule } from 'ng4-material-dropdown';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ Ng4DropdownModule ]
    // .. 
})
```

Then for example your using it in your `example.component.ts`
so in your `example.component.html`
you can write the code where you want to appear in the html, so write below code where you want to show the dropdown

```
<ng4-dropdown>
    <ng4-dropdown-button>
        Open Menu
    </ng4-dropdown-button>
    <ng4-dropdown-menu>
        <ng4-menu-item *ngFor="let page of pages">
            {{ page }}
        </ng4-menu-item>
        <div class='ng4-menu-divider'></div>
        <ng4-menu-item>
            With Divider
        </ng4-menu-item>
    </ng4-dropdown-menu>
</ng4-dropdown>
```

And you are good to go :)

Comment: Well, this is pretty much what is already being said in the documentation page. What is the purpose of repeating it here? My question was what is the let page or pages?

Comment: I thought you were talking about the template page that you were seeing on the npmjs page, so I explained in correct order, don't you think that you should use backticks `` to reference any variable in the code you are giving so that the person seeing the question is not confused that if you are referencing something in our code or somewhere else?

Comment: Even then how different is your explanation to what is already being described in the documentation? I have written clearly in my post above that the documentation is not clear on how to use it and you post a copy of the documentation and expect me to do what?

Comment: I appreciate that you wanted to help, but please help that would help me get around the problem!